# Button on-click is only working once

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why the OnClick event won't happen again in my code; see the jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/btcAx/2/

html:

```
<input id="LoginID" readonly="readonly" type="password" value="UserName"/>
<br/>
<input id="LoginPW" readonly="readonly" type="password" value="Password"/>
<br/>
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value=" Show/Hide Text " id="ChangeButton"/>
```

JS:

```
function change() {
  var inp1 = document.querySelector('#LoginID');
  var inp2 = document.querySelector('#LoginPW');

  if (inp1.type = "password") {
      inp1.type = "text";
      inp2.type = "text";
  }
  else {
      inp1.type = "password";
      inp2.type = "password";
  }
}
```

It will change from password to text type, but then it won't change back...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
if (inp1.type == "password") {
```

instead of

```
if (inp1.type = "password") {
```

Comment: Of course...that's what I get for not having my Coffee yet.

Comment: Happens the best once in a while ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (inp1.type = "password") {
```

should be

```
if (inp1.type == "password") {
```